# Why Home route not works in production - laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

Home route (/) not works in live server after composer update

it is showing :

> Method Not Allowed
> The requested method GET is not allowed for this URL.

> Additionally, a 405 Method Not Allowed error was encountered while
> trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
>
> ```
> Route: 
> Route::post('/', [WebController::class, 'index']);
> ```

all route except this works in live server

Comment: Home route's request type should be as "GET" instead of "POST".

Answer (score 1):

Please change `post` to `get`

```
Route: Route::post('/', [WebController::class, 'index']);
```

to

```
Route: Route::get('/', [WebController::class, 'index']);
```

Your error is [HTTP request methods](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Methods)

Answer (score 1):

Change

```
Route::post('/', [WebController::class, 'index']);
```

To

```
Route::get('/', [WebController::class, 'index']);
```

If you sure `index` is not the route you will post data to it, otherwise maybe you need to clear your cache:

```
php artisan route:cache
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the index method for GET request and Store method for POST request, and Update method for PUT request, and destroy method for DELETE.

You can use commonly use the following method,

```
Route::resource('/', WebController::class); // resource route
```

So that you can avoid mentioning the method name for each request.

Answer (score 0):

Use get:

```
Route::get('/', [WebController::class, 'index']);
```

or for more convenient use invokable controller if index is the only method in your controller:

```
php artisan make:controller WebController --invokable

Route::get('/', WebController::class);
```